# Return result from different activity than receiving activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, deep-linking

I have two apps. From the first app main activity it calls startActivityForResult() for launching second app's main activity. I know I can send result through Intent from second app's main activity.

But for some case if second app's main activity launches another activity and it finish the main activity then how I can send result to first app's main activity from second app's another activity?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have three activities - `A` in the first app and `B` and `C` in the second app.

I see two possible scenarios:

1. Chaining the result - `A` starts for result `B` starts for result `C`. The result from `C` is delivered to `B`, `B` delivers it as a result to `A`.
2. Using `Intent`s directly - don't start `B` for result, but use explicit `Intent`s to return the result to `A`. This means you should set `A`'s launch mode to `singleTop` and use appropriate flags to make sure you won't end up with multiple instances of the activity. You can also fire `Intent`s not directly to `A`, but to a `BroadcastReceiver` that will handle them accordingly.

Comment: My problem is from B I cannot start C for result. I need to finish B and start C. And from C I need to send result to A. Also I cannot make A as single Instance. What i am looking for is if there is any way I can send the result directly from C to A without BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I'd say no. The only way to communicate between components is `Intent`s. They are handled either by an activity, or a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Please give us a better idea about what do you need because with Intent you can solve your problem.